File attachment when user uploads a file
I am designing a chatbot and when user wants to attach a file, like say pdf or csv, How do they get attached the input message box? This is a sample csv file attachment How to implement the UI for this in vanilla JS? How to design this?

I'd suggest you to use an <input type="file" />, you can then style the input as you see fit via css pseudo selectors, or just make your own custom input like this: Example.
and if you were to go at it programmatically, you could add an "onInput" or just "input" (if you're using plain js) event listener to your element, and check if the event.target.files.length is larger than 1, then you can modify the style as you like, with this method you could also check the file type and other info and make changes accordingly, anything you need should be available inside the event object.
edit: to make it clear
window.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
    // Your code here...
  }
});

